# MKMapView place annotation at left

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I m currently working on an app with MKMapView and a lot of annotation

Details are shown as an overlay when annotation is touched (`didSelectAnnotationView`)

I want the overlay to be displayed entirely on the phone screen , but if I use

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinates:annotation.coordinates]
```

I miss a large part of the detail view at it s designed to take 80% of the phone screen.

So I looking for a method to place the touched annotation at left/vertical middle of the screen

How can I do that ?

I know I can use `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` to get an area of XX meters around a point and use setRegion to center on this point , but how could I get the left/middle point of this region ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using this page http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/36462-modifying-cllocations.html